# Combine -e and -n sed options

Tags: sed

I'm trying to convert all occurrences of a certain letter in the header of a file to lowercase, i can achieve this with 2 sed lines but i would like to use one instead.
What i'm trying is this:

```
cat file.txt | sed -e 'n 1p' -e 's/U/u/g'
```

Supposing that the letter i want to replace is the 'u'
I feel like i'm very close to it but for some reasons i get sed to complain about an extra char after the 'n' command, but in this case -n needs a parameter, so there should be no reason to complain.

Any hint?

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '1y/U/u/' file
```

Comment: @JBoy sed is a stream editor you must either send the output to another file or use the `-i` flag to overwrite the source file.

Answer (score 1):

try this (GNU sed):

```
sed '1s/U/u/g' file
```